# Spaces of differentiable functions - PDE's How to go from supremum to max?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, vector-spaces

I'm trying to understand a section in my book (I'm taking a course in Finite Element Methods for PDEs) which deals with some prerequisites for finite element methods, in this case spaces of differentiable/integrable functions. The section says the following:

> ...Below we introduce function spaces that are of fundamental
>   importance in the study of PDEs.
>
> Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded open set, then
>   $\mathcal{C}^k(\bar{\Omega})$ is the set of all functions such that
>   $D^{\alpha}u$ can be extended from $\Omega$ to its closure
>   $\bar{\Omega}$, for all multiindex
>   $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_n),$ $|\alpha|\leq k.$ The space
>   $\mathcal{C}^k(\bar{\Omega})$ is equipped with the supremum norm
>   defined by
>
> $$||u||_{\mathcal{C}^k(\bar{\Omega})}:=\sum_{\alpha\leq
>  k}\sup_{x\in\Omega}|D^{\alpha}u(x)|.\tag1$$
>
> Hence, e.g, for $k=1,$ we have
>
> $$||u||_{\mathcal{C}^1(\bar{\Omega})}:=\sum_{\alpha\leq
>  1}\sup_{x\in\Omega}|D^{\alpha}u(x)|=\sup_{x\in\Omega}|u(x)|+\sum^{n}_{i=1}\sup\left|\frac{\partial
>  u}{\partial x_i}\right|.\tag 2$$
>
> For simplicity we denote $\mathcal{C}^0(\bar{\Omega})$ by
>
> $$\mathcal{C(\bar{\Omega})}=\mathcal{C}^0(\bar{\Omega})=\sup_{x\in\Omega}|u(x)|=\max_{x\in\Omega}|u(x)|.\tag3$$

**Questions:**

1. I don't get what $D^{\alpha}u$ is. Is it the $\alpha$:th of $u$ and what does it mean to extend it to it's closure?
2. In $(2)$, how do they go to the third step where they get the sum from $i$ to $n$? I can't see the arithmetic. What happened to $D^{\alpha}u?$
3. In $(3)$, why can you go from $\sup$ to $\max$ like that for $k=1$?

Comment: Downvotes without stated reason will be ignored. Nothing I can do to improve my question if I don't know what the mistake is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $D^{\alpha}$ stands for a generic derivative of order $|\alpha|=\sum_i\alpha_i$. $\alpha$ is a multi-index, $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots \alpha_n)$ with non-negative integer entries. So for ex. $D^{(1,1)}u$ means the second derivative of $u$, once with respect to the first variable and once with respect to the second. The derivatives are assumed to exist in the open set $\Omega$ and also to be uniformly continuous there so they can be extended continuously to the boundary. Then you can replace the $\sup$ by a $\max$. If you only assume that the derivatives are bounded, you get the spaces $C^k(\Omega)$ and you need the sup.
2. If $k=1$ only the existence and continuity of first derivatives is assumed, and your possible $\alpha$'s with $|\alpha|=1$ are $(1,0,0,\dots 0), (0,1,0,\dots )$, etc. ($n-1$ zeros each time). Each of these corresponds to a first partial derivative.
3. Is a particular case of what I mentioned before. Since you assume continuity up to the boundary, the sup is achieved and becomes a max.

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot! 1) and 3) are down, I'm still a bit unclear, why do I add the term $\sup_{x\in\Omega}|u(x)|?$. Since we are only considering first derivatives I get the second term, but not the first term in RHS of $(2).$ Is it the case $\alpha = 0$?

Comment: Yes, that is the case. The zeroth order derivative is defined to be the original function.